# Confusion over Multiple Database Configuration

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to use multiple database where one DB is a default and the second DB is a :memory DB. From the description in the Docs (shown below), it sounds like the default routing should be fine. But it says that the objects are "sticky" to their original database. How is there an "Original" database?

When I first started to implement this, I expected that there would be a META in the Model classes that would specify its database, but that does not seem to be the case. I see examples where people have a Mapping of Apps to DB, which would be perfect for my scenario, but then they turn around and write a Routing anyway.

I don't want to have to always add the database to Save calls, as this would be prone to programming errors. Is there an official setting to map an App to a Database, or a Model to a Database? Or is it always required to write a Router to use multiple databases.

```
# Is DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING just a name that some developer chose to use or is it a
# real Django thing that would do what I want?
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'app1': 'default', 'app2': 'in_memory'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'in_memory': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

[Doc Content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing):

> The easiest way to use multiple databases is to set up a database routing scheme. The default routing scheme ensures that objects remain ‘sticky’ to their original database (i.e., an object retrieved from the foo database will be saved on the same database). The default routing scheme ensures that if a database isn’t specified, all queries fall back to the default database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a router. That is Django's mechanism for deciding which database should be used for a given operation. Being able to specify this in code is much more powerful and flexible than a simple mapping.

If your needs can be satisfied by a mapping then you can implement that functionality yourself; or perhaps there's already a third-party app for that. `DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING` is not a Django setting, which is why someone had to then write a router to make use of that value.